# Is there a way to overwrite a tif file's "ImageDescription"?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, metadata, tiff, scikit-image

I am making some modifications to .tif radiographs, that are required for further analysis.
However, further analysis (in a proprietary software...) expects to find in the header of these radiographs this field exactly:

> 'ImageDescription': 'slope = 2.13626E-05 \roffset = 0.00000E+00',

Because the slope and the offset are important parameters eventually.

I save my modified .tifs with tifffile (called from skimage.io):

> ```
> tifffile.imsave(outname, modified_image))
> ```

Now, when reading these novel .tifs and looking at the header, the 'ImageDescription' field has a lot of information:

> 'ImageDescription': '{"shape": [789, 960]}',
> 'StripOffsets': (304,),
> 'SamplesPerPixel': 1,
> 'RowsPerStrip': 789,
> 'StripByteCounts': (1514880,),
> 'XResolution': (1, 1),
> 'YResolution': (1, 1),
> 'ResolutionUnit': <RESUNIT.NONE: 1>,
> 'Software': 'tifffile.py'}

But I would like to replace all of this with the short string I mentioned earlier. The most promising function I had found was:

> ```
> tifffile.imsave(outname, modified_image, description='slope = 2.13626E-05 \roffset = 0.00000E+00'))
> ```

Yet, this does not seem to work. **It doesn't raise an error**, but reading the file "outname" and probing its header, it is still the long dict I do not want, and there is no mention of the string I do want.

By trying things around, I eventually raised errors in the form of 'ImageDescription' not being fill-able with a string, which startles me as "imsave" with the "description" field should precisely fill "ImageDescription" with a string...

Would anyone understand what is happening, and know of a workaround?

Comment: No, the `ImageDescription` field/tag has not "a lot of information". The `ImageDescription` is `'{"shape": [789, 960]}'` in the first case. In the second case there are two  `ImageDescription` fields, the first one is `'slope = 2.13626E-05 \roffset = 0.00000E+00'` and apparently it is ignored/discarded by whatever software you used to read the header. If you do not want the shape information stored in a second `ImageDescription` tag use `metadata=None` as documented.

Comment: @cgohlke Indeed, I had missed the second bracket.. I read the headers as: 
`import tifffile
with tifffile.TiffFile(refs.files[0]) as tif:
    tif_tags = {}
    for tag in tif.pages[0].tags.values():
        name, value = tag.name, tag.value
        tif_tags[name] = value`
And couldn't see the second "ImageDescription", but as you are right on the rest I'll assume on this too (well, perhaps it's just overwritten now that I think of it). Btw, thank you very much, using `metadata=None` was the fix. Would you like to write that as an answer and I'll mark it solved?

Answer (score 0):

The most competent tool for editing meta-data in images is probably `exiftool`, so you could do:

```
exiftool -Description='slope = 2.13626E-05 \roffset = 0.00000E+00' image.tif
```

Comment: Quite frustrating that such an application exists only as a terminal tool and not as a python library. That tool needs to be manually installed, cannot make it part of a larger pipeline